# How to sum two lists correctly?

Tags: c++, list

My task is to form a list Z by summing the elements of two lists.

If it is simpler, then I have two lists `X {x1, x2, ... xn}` & `Y {y1, y2, ..yn}` - >> I need to form Z.
X & Y size is the same.

`Zi = Xi + Yi`

I solve this problem, but I can’t. How can I solve the problem?

Code:

```
void IndividualTask(list<float>& lisX, list<float>& lisY) {
    list<float> Z;
    int i = 0;
    list<float>::iterator x = lisX.begin();
    list<float>::iterator y = lisY.begin();
    for (list<float>::iterator it = lisX.begin(); it != lisX.end(); ++it) {
        Z.push_back((x + i) + (y + i));
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: If `list<float>` is an `std::list`, you can't sum a `list<float>::iterator` to `int`, like `(x + i)`, you can only do `++` and `--` on them. You can only sum integer to random iterators, like the iterator from `std::vector`.

Comment: Basically, you want to sum 2 lists.  So there is no point to `i`, it was just given to you as a demonstration of what is wanted.  You need to increment BOTH `lisX` and `lisY` then `Z.push_back` `*xiter + *yiter` (or whatever you will call your iterators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::list` has no random accesss iterators, which means you can't add an a numeric value to it to advance them by several positions. You can only increment or decrement such an iterator by one at a time.

So the idea is to take two iterators and increment both inside the loop, add the values of both iterators and push the result to `Z`. Something like this:

```
void IndividualTask(const list<float>& lisX, const list<float>& lisY) {
    list<float> Z;
    auto x = lisX.begin();
    auto y = lisY.begin();
    while(x != lisX.end() && y != lisY.end()) {
        Z.push_back(*x + *y);

        ++x;
        ++y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you increment both iterators so you have access to both elements:

```cpp
std::list<float> IndividualTask(std::list<float>& lisX, std::list<float>& lisY) {
    std::list<float> Z;
    for (auto x = lisX.begin(), y = lisY.begin(); x != lisX.end() && y != lisY.end(); ++x, ++y) {
        Z.push_back(*x + *y);
    }
    return Z;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Research `std::accumulate` in your favorite C++ reference:

```
std::list<float> numbers;
//...
const float sum = std::accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0.0);
```